# Jquery menu not hiding on mouse leave

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following menu (which is just an icon that needs to display a drop down menu. I can get the menu to show and hide with toggle, but when I do that, as soon as I try to move to the displayed links it closes, if I trigger it on hover with with add class, I cant get the menu to go away. Does anyone have a way to smoothly show and hide this menu on mouse over and click?

```
   <div id="global_menu">
        <span id="show_global_menu" class="icons_large">(</span>
             <ul id="dropdown" class="hidden">
                 <span class="arrow-u" style="margin-top:-8px;"></span>
                 <li> @Ajax.ActionLink("Icon Legend", "font_legend", null, new AjaxOptions {           UpdateTargetId = "placeholder_extra1", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, HttpMethod = "GET" }, new { @class = "" })</li>
                <li><a href="../Home/Index" title="Sign Out">Sign Out</a></li>
                <li>Support</li>
            </ul>
</div>
    <script>
       $(document).ready(function () {
           if ($("ul#dropdown").hasClass("hidden")) {
               $("span#show_global_menu").hover(function () {
                   $("ul#dropdown").slideDown("slow");
               });
           };
       $("ul#dropdown").hover(function(){
           $("ul#dropdown").mouseout(function () {
               $("ul#dropdown").addClass("hidden");
           });
       });
      });
 </script>
```

Comment: You're binding an event handler inside another event handler.

Comment: what is the css for your .hidden class?

Comment: it's hidden with display: none

Comment: sorry, also the class="hidden" hides the menu as well

Comment: Again, `hover()` is a shortcut for `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`, and accepts two functions, one for each. Everytime your mouse enters the element, you attach a new event handler for `mouseout`, which is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use it:

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function () {
       if ($("ul#dropdown").hasClass("hidden")) {
           $("span#show_global_menu").hover(function () {
               $("ul#dropdown").slideDown("slow");
           });
       };

       $("ul#dropdown").mouseleave(function () {
           $("ul#dropdown").slideUp('slow');
       });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you!!!  This has given me a huge headache for being such a little menu. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try somesing like this:
       
           $(document).ready(function () {

```
$("span#show_global_menu").hover(function () {
     $("ul#dropdown").slideDown("slow");
},function(){
      $("ul#dropdown").slideUp("slow");
});


      });
 </script>
```

Comment: You should make sure to stop the previous animation if you use one both at `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` or you could end up creating an annoying queue of animation. `$("ul#dropdown").stop().slideUp("slow");`

Comment: This works, but as soon as I leave my icon (#show_global_menu) and try and hover my list (ul#dropdown) the list slidesUP.